# Increment variable number inside for loop in Java

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, increment

Currently working on a Java project, however I've encountered a bit of a problem involving having a variable number increment in Java, simply due to my lack of knowledge; I'm a beginner.

I'm used to using Batch files, where for this I'd do something along the lines of;

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do {
set variable%%a = (The value)
}
```

Where each time it goes through the loop, it would set a new variable; `variable1, variable2, variable3` etc. However, hence being here, I have no idea what I'd do to put a value into a variable name in Java, in which the variable would increment each time the loop was passed as declared by `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. What would I have to do to declare that value in the name of a variable, such as `variable(i) = 5` continuously?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (variable name as key, value as value):

```
final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i; i < 10; i++) {
    map.put("variable" + i, i);
}
// use the map, for example: map.get("variable5") // = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. You have to make use of array or collections to set a collection of values.